Why is ReactJS not reflecting changes in array to my UI?
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Recommend() {
  const [animeName, setAnimeName] = useState("");
  const [anilistURL, setanilistURL] = useState("");
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [loadingReviews, setLoadingReviews] = useState(false);
  const [reviewTitles, setreviewTitles] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      setreviewTitles([]);
      setanilistURL("");
      setErrorMsg("");

      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/get-anilist-url", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          anime_title: animeName,
        }),
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        setErrorMsg(errorData.error || "Unable to get response");
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      setanilistURL(data.anilist_url || "No URL found");
      setErrorMsg("");
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorMsg("An error occurred: " + error.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
      getReviews();
    }
  };

  const getReviews = async () => {
    try {
      setLoadingReviews(true);
      setErrorMsg("");
      const anilistReviewsURL = anilistURL + "/reviews";
      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/scrape/get-review-titles",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ reviewsLink: anilistReviewsURL }),
        }
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      if (!response.ok) {
        setErrorMsg(data.error || "Unable to get response");
      }
      setreviewTitles((prevTitles) => [
        ...prevTitles,
        data.reviewTitles
      ]);
      setErrorMsg("");

    } catch (error) {
      setErrorMsg("An error occurred: " + error);
    }
    finally {
      setLoadingReviews(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col h-screen bg-slate-700">
      <div className="flex-grow bg-slate-600 p-5 font-mono">
        {loading && <div className="text-white">Loading...</div>}
        {errorMsg && <div className="text-red-500">{errorMsg}</div>}
        {anilistURL && (
          <div className="text-yellow-100">
            <p>Anilist URL:</p>
            <a href={anilistURL} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
              {anilistURL}
            </a>
          </div>
        )}
        {loadingReviews && <div className="text-white">Loading...</div>}
        {reviewTitles && (
          reviewTitles.map((reviewTitle) => {
            (
              <div className = "text-yellow-500 pt-3">
                {reviewTitle}
              </div>
            )
          })
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="p-4 flex items-center justify-between bg-slate-800">
        <h3 className="text-gray-500 text-3xl font-mono">
          Enter anime to be analyzed
        </h3>
        <textarea
          type="text"
          className="bg-slate-700 font-mono text-white text-2xl p-3 border-none outline-none w-full rounded-full"
          placeholder="Enter your prompt..."
          value={animeName}
          onChange={(e) => setAnimeName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button
          className="bg-slate-700 font-mono text-white text-2xl p-4 rounded-full hover:bg-slate-600 transition duration-200 ml-5"
          onClick={handleSubmit}
        >
          Analyze
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

This is my code. My problem is mainly with the review titles. They are not displaying on the UI even though I am setting their state in the getReviews() function. There is nothing wrong with my API endpoints I have tested them with Postman and CORS is also handled. The Anilist URL is being displayed correctly after I set its state in the handleSubmit() function even Loading... from loadingReviews state appears but the first time I click on the analyze button it displays the anilist URL but says failed to fetch status 404 for the review titles and the second time I click analyze it displays the anilist URL as before shows Loading... from the loadingReviews state but doesn't display anything. From what I have researched it looks like the problem is with the asynchronous nature of useState but I am not really able to understand how to solve this problem. When I console log the reviewTitles it works albeit after clicking the second time(the first time I get a failed to fetch status 404 as I said before) but nothing is displayed on the frontend as I expect. How do I solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated greatly.
I have tried setting reviewTitles using a callback function but that did not work either. Console logging helped me see that there was a problem but I do not understand why nothing displays the first time I click analyze even though I console logged directly after setting the state. I thought of using useEffect() but this does not seem to be the correct usecase for it.

Make sure to add a key prop to your div when mapping, you should’ve got a warning about that in your console as well.

Oh yes I remember the key should be an index or something yes I will try that. Also can you review my code to check why I am getting an error after the first time I click on the analyze button. I feel my code does not follow best practices somewhere

Yeah, ideally it shouldn’t be an index, it should be something unique to that element (that stays the same across rerenders, regardless of the position of the element, so index isn’t a great option). The review title might be a good key if it’s unique, otherwise you might need to associate an id with each review.

You’d be getting 404 on the first click because anilistURL state doesn’t get updated until the next rerender of your component, it’ll always be the same for that execution/render of your component, so when you call getReviews(), your state won’t be updated, I’d suggest passing data.anilist_url into your getReviews() function to use that instead of your state. See this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately

Yes thanks a lot for your help I used a useEffect() to run getReviews() whenever anilistURL gets updated is that also a good solution?

The useEffect solution is ok-ish… but putting getReviews() into a useEffect will trigger an additional rerender (you update your URL, that causes a rerender, this fires the useEffect which then updates your review titles, causing another render). I’d suggest using a temporary variable like the solution here, although it may be a bit finicky (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877875/5648954). (Also more info on the effect solution, and why some might not consider it the best option: https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect)

I see. I ran the getReviews(data.anilist_url) as you suggested and it worked so I won't be using useEffect(). However I am still confused about why I cannot just pass the anilistURL directly because I am setting its state right? Does the state set only after the UI is rendered? Is that why I cannot pass anilistURL directly? And also, what are the standard usecases for useEffect() since using it for transforming data or updating variables does not seem to be recommended according to the article you shared.

Also thanks for your help! This is my first time using stackoverflow and it has proved very helpful!

"Does the state set only after the UI is rendered?" Yep, that's exactly right. It also can't be set in that render, because if you think about it, your anilistURL is just a normal JS variable. Since it's const, it can't be reassigned and updated, and since it holds a primitive string (which are immutable/readonly), there's no way that it can be changed by any JS code. So rather than updating the variable which can't happen, which React rerenders your component, it re-executes your function and thus is able to recreate your state variable with the new updated value.

This article has some good examples on when effects are generally useful. Typically if you want to do something onmount, like fetching data via an API call, a useEffect is a good option.

Guys I have found an answer to my question I added a useEffect() hook to run getReviews() function whenever there is a change in the anilistURL instead of running it directly from the handleSubmit function and mapped the review titles using a key prop(thanks to Nick Parsons) which seemed to solve the problem for me. Here is the working code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Recommend() {
  const [animeName, setAnimeName] = useState("");
  const [anilistURL, setAnilistURL] = useState("");
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [loadingReviews, setLoadingReviews] = useState(false);
  const [reviewTitles, setReviewTitles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (anilistURL) {
      getReviews(anilistURL);
    }
  }, [anilistURL]);

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      setAnilistURL("");
      setReviewTitles([]);
      setErrorMsg("");

      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/get-anilist-url", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          anime_title: animeName,
        }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        setErrorMsg(errorData.error || "Unable to get response");
        setLoading(false);
        return;
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      setAnilistURL(data.anilist_url || "No URL found");
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorMsg("An error occurred: " + error.message);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const getReviews = async (url) => {
    try {
      setLoadingReviews(true);
      setErrorMsg("");
      const anilistReviewsURL = url + "/reviews";

      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/scrape/get-review-titles",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ reviewsLink: anilistReviewsURL }),
        }
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        setErrorMsg(errorData.error || "Unable to get response");
        setLoadingReviews(false);
        return;
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      setReviewTitles(data.reviewTitles || []);
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorMsg("An error occurred: " + error.message);
    } finally {
      setLoadingReviews(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col h-screen bg-slate-700">
      <div className="flex-grow bg-slate-600 p-5 font-mono">
        {loading && <div className="text-white">Loading...</div>}
        {errorMsg && <div className="text-red-500">{errorMsg}</div>}
        {anilistURL && (
          <div className="text-yellow-100">
            <p>Anilist URL:</p>
            <a href={anilistURL} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
              {anilistURL}
            </a>
          </div>
        )}
        {loadingReviews && <div className="text-white">Loading reviews...</div>}
        {reviewTitles.length > 0 && (
          <div>
            <h3 className="text-white">Review Titles:</h3>
            {reviewTitles.map((reviewTitle, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="text-yellow-500 pt-3">
                {reviewTitle}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="p-4 flex items-center justify-between bg-slate-800">
        <h3 className="text-gray-500 text-3xl font-mono">
          Enter anime to be analyzed
        </h3>
        <textarea
          type="text"
          className="bg-slate-700 font-mono text-white text-2xl p-3 border-none outline-none w-full rounded-full"
          placeholder="Enter your prompt..."
          value={animeName}
          onChange={(e) => setAnimeName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button
          className="bg-slate-700 font-mono text-white text-2xl p-4 rounded-full hover:bg-slate-600 transition duration-200 ml-5"
          onClick={handleSubmit}
        >
          Analyze
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

